# If vs boolean assignment speed C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, variable-assignment, updates, updating

I have a function that is run ~60 times per second on a Nintendo DS (~50MHz CPU, ~3MB RAM). In this function I need to execute `changed()` only if the boolean has changed from false to true. Does the if statement increase the speed or decrease it?

```
bool variable = false; //Externally changed and accessed variable
bool oldVar; //Previous state of variable

void update()
{
    //////////////////////////////////
    if (!variable)
    //////////////////////////////////
        oldVar = variable;

    if (variable && !oldVar)
    {
        oldVar = true;
        changed();
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CPU architecture of Nintendo DS and how its branch prediction behaves, so if it's me I would do some profiling under real conditions.

Comment: Can you just run both one after another 100000 times and print the time each takes to see the difference?

Comment: If he compiles with optimizations on it probably all vanishes anyway and ends up in 2,3 assembler instructions.

Comment: Early optimisation efforts are the very definition of evil. Write code that explains intent clearly. Let the optimiser do its work. It knows the cpu better than you ever will. Furthermore, an event occurring 60 times per second is *nothing* to a modern cpu. Seeking to save one memory fetch is a waste of your valuable time.

Comment: You probably mean 50 MHz processor because at 50Hz you would have no chance of executing anything at 60FPS.

Comment: @TonyJiang I can tell you its really bad. And not only that but the compiler provided by nintendo is a piece of crap that optimizes nothing.

Comment: @RichardHodges: The question isn't about a modern CPU. And the code has already been written, so it isn't premature optimisation. And, despite popular opinion, optimisers aren't magic and often don't know the typical program flow as well as a human might.

Comment: Should not watch BBT while reading SO questions. Hard to stay serious...anyway: If you really worry about that, here the ultimate solution: Compile the function with gcc or clang for arm with -O3, then pack the disassembled code into inline assembly for your Nintendo ARM processor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Hi Mike, this is a playstation 3 - it's certainly 'modern' in comparison to any processor where one tiny operation every 20ms is going to matter. Anything built in the past 3 decades is modern in this respect.

Comment: @RichardHodges: It's a 15-year-old embedded CPU, running at a speed similar to that of a 25-year-old PC; so I wouldn't call it modern myself. You're probably right that sixty memory accesses per second isn't going to make a noticeable impact (although not knowing the memory architecture of the Nintendo DS, I'd have to measure it to say so as definitively as you). But, having written and optimised a fair amount of code for similar platforms, I'd say it's worth writing code efficiently where that doesn't hurt readability; and not worth arguing about "premature" optimisation.

Comment: Isn't it fair to say that elegantly expressed code has a good chance of being close to optimally efficient? i.e. express your logic clearly, don't seek to lead the compiler into an optimal implementation and don't frustrate the compiler by introducing un-necessary side effects that it is forced to reproduce in optimised code? Of course optimisers are not magic - they look at expressed intent and seek to implement it in as few expensive operations as possible. The emphasis here being on *expressed* intent, rather than merely *intent* :)

Comment: @RichardHodges: Having worked with quite a few compilers for ARM and other embedded processors: no. The compiler often needs help generating optimal code. Even if it does do "obvious" optimisations (which isn't guaranteed), it won't know whether or not this particular function would be faster with or without the conditional, since it depends on memory timings (which it might not know), and on how often the variable changes (which it doesn't know), and on whether you're trying to optimise the average case (to reduce overall CPU load) or the worst case (to meet a real-time constraint).

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, this completely depends on how often you expect there to be a change.

If there is a change 90% of the time, over long periods of time you will probably get a noticeable boost in performance with the "if".

Read speeds are far faster than write speeds, so only reading and not writing will save you a lot of time if you will rarely have to write(change the variable).

If you will have to change the variable more often than not, you will have to both read and write each time, obviously being less efficient than just writing. However since reads are so quick it might be barely noticable at only 60 times a second.

Comment: In my case, ~every 60 seconds there's a change with it being true ~70% of the time.

Comment: It is pretty hard to guess as I do not know the ratio of read:write speeds of a Nintendo DS.

As I said in the comment, consider timing it after running it 100,000 or 1,000,000 times with each version of the code and see which is quicker.

Comment: At only 60 times per second, this difference could easily be in the region of a millisecond per second. Negligable.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that it's really going to make much of a difference, but I would instead suggest cleaning this up for readability/maintainability:

```
bool variable = false; //Externally changed variable
bool oldVar; //Previous state of variable

void update()
{
    //update if going from false to true
    if(variable && !oldVar) {
        changed();
    }
    oldVar = variable;
}
```